# What is the maximum Thread Size for SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor? - Spring Batch

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-batch

I need to run a big migration job and transform a lot of data. 
For this reason I implemented SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor...

Is there any Best Practice for the ConcurrencyLimit?

```
public final String THREAD_MAX = 10;

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
       SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("spring_batch");
       asyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(THREAD_MAX);

       return asyncTaskExecutor;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I implemented SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"? Do you mean you use it in your JobLauncher? If it is the case, I really recommend using the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` because the `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` does *not* reuse threads: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html

Answer (score 0):

That depends quite a bit on the type of load you are generating. Is it mostly CPU bound or IO bound?

If it is CPU bound then you won't gain anything if you have more threads than CPU cores. Actually, you'll lose due to unnecessary context switches and useless scheduling overhead.

If it is IO bound you need to experiment where, given your hardware setup and the exact type of load, the sweet-spot of parallelism is that yields the highest throughput. I'd start with a low single digit number of threads and then keep doubling it to quickly get a feel on how throughput changes with the number of threads. Don't be surprised if your best result is with a fairly small number of threads.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So it`s a good idea to set in cpu count, i would guess =)

Comment: If you set the cpu count as thread count and, when running the job, all cores are 100% busy at all times, then that's the maximum you can achieve.